# CSS animations transform qustion

Tags: html, css

I'm new with css transform property, but I'm trying to learn and to make my first animation. Let's say that I made what I wanted, but have one error and can't find how to fix that.

Jsfiddle example is in comment.

Problem is that when I hover first div anther two moves down, and it's same with another two divs when I hover another one. Just want to keep divs fixed.

I'm not sure am I doing something wrong with animation or with something else.

Thank you!

Comment: jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/snoopy15/6a0zon6c/2/

Comment: apply a float:left to your .social-media a  and it works

Comment: O my God I can't believe that this was the problem. :-0 Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply a float:left to your .social-media a and remove the display:inline-block. The inline-block style pushes the elements up when your animation happens.

```
  .social-media a
  {
   float:left;
  }
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6a0zon6c/4/

**Edit** Your div (.social-media) that is wrapping all the other divs has no specific height. Therefor if you hover over one element, the icon moves to the top, making the size of the wrapping div bigger and your other element align to that new size, giving the impression of 'falling'. If you for example set a fixed height to your .social-media div and do an overflow:hidden on that div as well, you counter the moving effect as well. The float goes around this effect, since a floated element isn't really in the normal flow of the DOM but goes to the side (left or right), hence ignoring the height changes of the parent div.

Comment: But just a small question. need to understand, what was happening before applying float:left.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is make the anchors float so they will position correctly:

```
.social-media a {
  float: left;
}
```

See an updated JSfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/6a0zon6c/3/